# Unexpected char in the http get json file while using org.apache.http

Tags: java, json, apache-httpclient-4.x

There is a json file on my websites floder.

Here is the content:

```
{
"IsUpdateForcibly": "false",
"Version": "1.0",
"ReleaseNote": "OHOHOHOHOHO",
"DownloadLink": "http://192.168.1.37:11604/APK/FrauleinProject.apk"
}
```

If I use the browser to see,like http://localhost:11604/Content/CheckVersion.json, the result is same as thefile's content.

While I use the Java code. the response content is a little bit different.

```
 ?{
"IsUpdateForcibly": "false",
"Version": "1.0",
"ReleaseNote": "OHOHOHOHOHO",
"DownloadLink": "http://192.168.1.37:11604/APK/FrauleinProject.apk"
}
```

Why there is a question mark in the front of the  string?

Here is is my httpclient code.

```
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
import sun.misc.IOUtils;
import sun.net.www.http.HttpClient;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.WinHttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class DesUtil {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


     CloseableHttpClient httpclient = WinHttpClients.createDefault();
        // There is no need to provide user credentials
        // HttpClient will attempt to access current user security context through
        // Windows platform specific methods via JNI.
        try {

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost:11604/Content/CheckVersion.json");

            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");


                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new ResponseHandler<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public String handleResponse(
                            final HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
                        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                        if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
                            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                            return entity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(entity) : null;
                        } else {
                            throw new ClientProtocolException("Unexpected response status: " + status);
                        }
                    }

                };


                String json=  new String(httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt");
                out.println(json);
                out.close();
                System.out.println(json);

                JSONObject obj = JSONObject.fromObject(json);
                System.out.println(obj==null);
                Sb newSB= (Sb)JSONObject.toBean(obj,Sb.class);
                System.out.println(newSB==null);
                System.out.println(newSB.IsUpdateForcibly);
                System.out.println(newSB.Version);
                System.out.println(newSB.ReleaseNote);
                System.out.println(newSB.DownloadLink);             

            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                 System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                response.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
       }
        finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
        System.out.println("end");

        }


}
```

Comment: Try using `EntityUtils.toString(entity, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

Comment: Reply @RC. :So I use "EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)" as what you said ,but It is same as  the old one.

Comment: Download [a curl package](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html), run `curl -vvv http://localhost:11604/Content/CheckVersion.json` in a terminal and post the output.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by adding "UTF-8"

```
String str= EntityUtils.toString(entity2);
```

to

```
String str= EntityUtils.toString(entity2,"UTF-8");
```

**demo:**

```
private static void sendPost() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
{
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:8911/crr");
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("crawlId", "123"));
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("transType", "0"));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
    CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    try {
        System.out.println(response2.getStatusLine());
        HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();

        String str= EntityUtils.toString(entity2,"UTF-8");
        System.out.println(str);
    } finally {
        response2.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably stems from a Unicode BOM character, a zero-width space in Unicode that is used in UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE at the beginning of a file to mark it as Unicode: `\uFEFF`. It is redundant, unneeded, and - as seen here - causes several problems.

It was replaced with a question mark, as the character encoding of the saved text could not represent the BOM character.

As @zhizhi mentioned, better safe the JSON as UTF-8. Still better is to remove the BOM.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt", "UTF-8");
json = json.replaceFirst("^\uFEFF", "");
```

Mind that removing the BOM poses a UTF-8 recognition problem for Notepad.